# How to use mocks in this case?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, n-tier-architecture

Here is my problem:

I have an n-tiers application for which I have to write unit tests. Unit tests are for the business layer.

I have a method to test called `Insert()` and this one use two protected methods from inheritance and call directly a method from Data access layer.

So I have made a mock object for the DAL. But here is the point, in a *(edit :) protected* method from inheritance, It will use another object from DAL! It seems it is not possible to mock this one!

Here is the method for test code:

```
public int Insert(MYOBJECT aMyObject)
    {
            //first inherited method use the FIRSTDALOBJECT so the mock object --> No problem
            aMyObject.SomeField= FirstInherited();

            //Second inherited method (see after) --> my problem
            aMyObject.SomeOtherField = SecondInherited();

            // Direct access to DALMethod, use FIRSTDALOBJECT so the mock -->No Problem
            return this.FIRSTDALOBJECT.Insert(aMyObject);             
     }
```

Here is the SecondInherited method:

```
 protected string SecondInherited ()
    { 
        // Here is my problem, the mock here seems not be possible for seconddalobject                                          
        return ( new SECONDDALOBJECT Sdo().Stuff());
    }
```

And here is the unit test method code :

```
    [TestMethod()]
    public void InsertTest()
    {
        BLLCLASS_Accessor target = new BLLCLASS_Accessor();
        MYOBJECT aMyObject = new MYOBJECT { SomeField = null, SomeOtherField = 1 };
        int expected = 1;
        int actual;

        //mock
        var Mock = new Mock<DAL.INTERFACES.IFIRSTDALOBJECT>();
        //Rec for calls
        List<SOMECLASS> retour = new List<SOMECLASS>();
        retour.Add(new SOMECLASS());

        //Here is the second call (last from method to test)
        Mock
            .Setup(p => p.Insert(aMyObject))
            .Returns(1);

        // Here is the first call (from the FirstInherited())
        Mock
            .Setup(p => p.GetLast())
            .Returns(50);
        // Replace the real by the mock
        target.demande_provider = Mock.Object;

        actual = target.Insert(aMyObject);
        Assert.AreEqual(/*Some assertion stuff*/);
    }
```

Thank you for reading all the question :-) Hope it is clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Your text seems to say that `SecondInherited` is `private`, while in the code example it is `protected`. Anyway, if it is not `protected`, I would suggest changing its access qualifier as the first step.</strike>

You can **create a subclass solely for testing purposes, and override `SecondInherited` there** to avoid creating `SECONDDALOBJECT` and just return some value suitable for your tests.

This way you can **write your first unit test(s) with minimal changes to the class being tested, thus minimizing the chances of breaking something**. Once you have the unit tests in place, these allow you to do more refactoring safely, eventually achieving a better (more testable / mockable) design, such as using [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), or a Factory. (I would probably prefer an [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) over [Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) here, as the latter would practically force you to keep subclassing the tested class).

The fundamental, highly recommended book for learning this technique (and many more) is [*Working Effectively With Legacy Code*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131177052).

Comment: @bAN, thanks for the clarification, this way the solution is even easier.

Answer (score 2):

No chance to mock this with MOQ.
You have two options:

1. Use TypeMock or Moles to mock the `SECONDDALOBJECT` class
2. Refactor the code, so the instance of `SECONDDALOBJECT` isn't created in the way it is, but in a way that can be mocked (Factory method, DI, ...) (prefered!)